# One-drive photos Sharing

Tags: onedrive, sharing

Ive recently had someone go through my one drive app and there was a photo shared so I'm wanting to know is it possible to somehow find out who the photo was shared with

Answer (score 0):

If you shared a link then there is no way for you to find, who have accessed it or not. Means anyone with that link can access to the file without notifying you..